# Calculating the maximum depth of the opening bracket

Tags: algorithm

There are brackets of four shapes as follows.

> Type 1 : '(' or ')'
>
> Type 2 : '{' or '}'
>
> Type 3 : '[' or ']'
>
> Type 4 : '<' or '>'

If there is a string composed of brackets of four shapes only as above, write a function to return the depth of innermost brackets. The depth is defined by the extent of overlapping. The depth of the outermost brackets is 1, the depth of brackets inside of the outermost brackets is 2, and the depth of brackets inside one more is 3.

Example:-
“{([])[()(<>)]}“
 here the max depth is 4. Let the string contains valid brackets.

Comment: What was your attempts? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't specify the language, I'll do this in Python. It's also so close to pseudocode that you can easily translate it to other languages:

Something like this:

```
def maxdepth(s):
    depth = 0
    maxdepth = 0
    for c in s:
        print c
        if c in '[({<':
            depth = depth + 1
            maxdepth = max(maxdepth, depth)
            print depth, maxdepth
        elif c in '])}>':
            depth = depth - 1
            print depth, maxdepth
    return maxdepth
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple implementation:

```
open_brackets = '[', '{', '(', '<'
close_brackets = ']', '}', ')', '>'

depth = 0
max_depth = 0

for character in string
    if open_brackets contains character
        depth++
        if depth > max_depth
            max_depth = depth
    else if close_brackets contains character
        depth--

return max_depth
```

Note that that doesn't care about mis-matched brackets (e.g. it finds '[(])' acceptable).

If you did want to check for mis-matched brackets, you'd need a stack. When you encounter an open bracket, push it onto the stack. When you encounter a close bracket, pop the top bracket off the stack and make sure it's the same type as that close bracket. Something like....

```
open_brackets = '[', '{', '(', '<'
close_brackets = ']', '}', ')', '>'

max_depth = 0
stack = new stack

for character in string
    if open_brackets contains character
        stack.push character
        if stack.count > max_depth
            max_depth = stack.count
    else if close_brackets contains character
        desired_closing_bracket = stack.pop
        if desired_closing_bracket is not the same type as character
           throw exception "Mis-matched bracket. Got {character}, expected {desired_closing_bracket"

return max_depth
```

This algorithm's weakness is that it the `stack.pop` line will probably fail with an exception if you get more closing brackets than opening brackets. It might be wise to anticipate or catch this exception, and provide a more useful error message.

Also, if you want to check there weren't more opening brackets than closing brackets, check whether the stack's empty after the loop.